# .htaccess not working with Laravel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.1 with a PuPHPet VM using Apache (so not Homestead).

I've got the default .htaccess in my public dir;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've been in to the apache2.conf;

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all granted
</FilesMatch>

<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And I've restarted apache2;

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But I still get a not found on;

http://192.168.56.131/auth/register

But not on;

http://192.168.56.131/public/auth/register

So I'm not sure what to try now. Part of it must work because the `index.php` is no longer required

---

### *** UPDATE ***

This is working;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

But this does not;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

It just doesn't like the whole "public" thing.

This is an updated partial of my apache2.conf file;

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

So frustrating! I don't understand what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache config should go within the vhost config file, not htaccess.

PuPHPet uses php-fpm, mod_php support was dropped several months ago.

Comment: Then why is the index.php removed easily enough?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```